# How to check a value in dataframe column is string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 2Lakh records, one of the numeric column(Volume) contains the strings. Would like to access those rows and replace with most frequent value.

I tried below but getting an error.

```
df[df["Volume"].dtype!=np.int64]
```

KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Don't use "Lakh". This a word used in South Asian countries to denote 100 thousand. Stackoverflow is a international community so if you want people to respond you should use more general terms.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code evaluates to

```
df[(CONDITIONAL)]
```

So you end up trying to get the key/index "True" of df. If you wrote it as:

```
df["Volume"].dtype!=np.int64
```

Then you should be better off.